# How to rewrite this require module with import module syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to import this module using ES6. It's currently written as:

`var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;`

I have:

`import neo4j from 'neo4j-driver;'`

But I have no idea how to handle the .v1?

Reference: http://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/

Thank you.

Comment: Just use `neo4j.v1` after the `import` line.

Comment: I tried this: `import neo4j.v1 from 'neo4j-driver';` and still getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `v1` is a member of the module, you can use `import`'s [`member` syntaxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Including `{ member as alias }`:

```
import { v1 as neo4j } from 'neo4j-driver';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript destructuring and do `import { v1 as neo4j } from 'neo4j-driver'` which can then be used in your code like `neo4j.someMethod()` or whatever (I'm not familiar with the library in question).

See here for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import